# Where is my source code on docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-web-api

I used following docker script to build and run my ASP.NET Web API project on .net 4.6.1 framework.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY TestWebAPI/*.csproj ./TestWebAPI/
COPY TestWebAPI/*.config ./TestWebAPI/
RUN nuget restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY TestWebAPI/. ./TestWebAPI/
WORKDIR /app/TestWebAPI
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release


FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2 AS runtime
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY --from=build /app/TestWebAPI/. ./
```

In the first step I am setting app folder as my working directory. But after creating container, I do not see any folder name app on my C:

```
--To create Image
docker image build --tag testwebapi --file .\Dockerfile .

--To run container
docker container run --detach --publish 80 testwebapi

--To see containers content
docker exec -i -t a1da40af6b3c powershell
```

[image]

**Where does docker keep the source code?**

Comment: It doesn't necessarily; it only keeps what's explicitly `COPY`d or `ADD`ed in.  If you can add a binary executable to an image, often the source code and build tools won't be included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find your files in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`.

Note that your `Dockerfile` has two `FROM` lines:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk AS build
...
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2 AS runtime
```

This is using a relatively new Docker feature called [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). Basically, only the instructions from the second (and last) stage determine what's copied into the actual image:

```
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY --from=build /app/TestWebAPI/. ./
```

Note that `--from=build` references the output of first stage - think of it as a temporary image. `/inetpub/wwwroot` is the `WORKDIR` of the second stage, so that's where you'll find the files from the final `COPY` step.